# Eclipse RCP Hotdeployment to exported version

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on Eclipse RCP, of which i explored few concepts required for my project, I knew how to export RCP product(which is portable).

1. My development approach was, for each Java File change I'm deleting
   the previously exported product and exporting it again. I think my
   approach is dumb, there might be better ways.
2. For a fix in java file, each time exporting is time consuming. As a
   workaround I thought of replacing the class file generated in bin to
   my plugin jar, but for my java file, there are multiple class files
   generated with classname$1.class, etc. It was difficult to replace
   all these class files into my plugin.jar.

What is the better practice in such situation. What do expert RCP developers do, for a java change to be reflected to a product exported version without deleting product or creating new. Isn't there any hot-deployment kinda thing, as an analogy Jsp change into Application server is a hot deployment.

Looking forward for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Day to day I generally just run my product in the debugger - code changes are reflected immediately.
However you can use p2 to update a previously exported product - although this requires exporting a new version of the product first to generate a compatible p2 repository. An alternative is to push your changes to a build server and have it build the new product and p2 repository for you. I find [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) is a good choice to help automate my builds.